# How to Sort in Unix using a specific location

Tags: unix, sorting

Hi I have a large text file that I want to sort using a specific location (e.g. 6-12 characters)

Ex.
Input:

```
12345222 ABC DEG123456 AAA BBB
12345111VABCGDEG123456 AAA BBB
12345111AABCGDEG123456HAAAJBBB
```

Output (using the 6-12characters as the sort key):

```
12345111AABCGDEG123456HAAAJBBB
12345111VABCGDEG123456 AAA BBB
12345222 ABC DEG123456 AAA BBB
```

Note: some of the values in the sort key may or may have values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sort -t$'\n' -k1.6,1.12 file_to_be_sorted
12345111AABCGDEG123456HAAAJBBB
12345111VABCGDEG123456 AAA BBB
12345222 ABC DEG123456 AAA BBB
```